# How to get more than 3 international clocks in Windows?

Tags: windows, clock, time-zone

Is there a way to get more than 3 international clocks in Windows Vista (or later)?

This [How To Geek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24672/beginner-geek-view-different-time-zones-in-the-windows-7-tray-clock/) describes how to add two extra international clocks but I'd like more.

Comment: With regards to the bounty: It is impossible and the only one who can provide this to you is Microsoft, given that the popup only reads out the clocks you configured and not more than that...

Comment: Question updated to reflect modern Windows OS which can run gadgets (And since it's the same answer for Vista to 10)...

Comment: It should be pointed out that since Windows 7 they have been discontinued for in favour or Window Store Apps.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13787/gadgets-have-been-discontinued

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Right-click on the desktop
2. Pick Gadgets
3. Drag a Clock to the desktop
4. Hover near the top right of the clock and click the spanner
5. Pick your time zone
6. Repeat until you have all the clocks you want.

Comment: I like step 6. http://i47.tinypic.com/33yrfo1.jpg

Comment: This does work but none of the available clocks shows AM/PM or day - since I'm in Auckland and want to show London / UTC this isn't very helpful! ;)  I'm adding a bounty to see if there's a better way than this - ideally it'd allow extra clocks in the existing status bar popup.

Comment: I'd also prefer the clocks to not be on the desktop if possible.

Comment: gadgets is not available in windows 10

Answer (score 19):

In windows 10, you can use the alarms and clock apps with the Alarms & Clock.

[image]

You can add up to 10 clocks.

You can right click these to pin them to your start menu too =)

Comment: It's actually only up to 10 clocks. Not as many as you want.

Comment: It's now called `Alarms & Clock` and pinning to the start menu has some stupid animation that causes latency in viewing... any way to disable that?

Answer (score 6):

Windows 7 supports only two additional time zones. If you want to set up more than two additional time zones, then you will have to install some 3rd party software like [this one](http://www.sobolsoft.com/showtimezone/).

Comment: Hmm, that'd do the job but I hope there's something out there that looks a bit nicer!

Answer (score 3):

I found this freeware app from Microsoft, [Microsoft Time Zone](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11115), but it requires .NET framework 1.1.

I've got .NET 4 installed but it doesn't seem to work with that, so I'm not sure this is viable on Windows 7, unless someone can suggest a fix.

[image]

I found this from [this page](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-free-multiple-timezone-world-clock.htm), but most of the other apps listed look either sketchy, bloated or out of date.

Comment: You can download and install .NET 1.1 manually. .NET 4.0 is incompatible to previous .NET versions, including .NET 2 and 3 which are also incompatible with .NET 1.1 themselves.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a complete answer to your question you may find something of value hiding in the registry at:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\TimeDate\AdditionalClocks

Adding a 3rd entry doesn't seem to provide anything useful but it may well be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Nope, tried... added clock number 3, wasn't showing up.

Answer (score 0):

The [World Clock - Orange](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/downloads/personalize/gadgets) desktop gadget, which I think is something to do with Orange France, is another option.

[image: World clock widget screenshot]

Plus points:

- It looks quite nice
- It's readable
- It's configurable to show 24/12 hour time and analogue/digital.

Minus points:

- It'll only show the day/date on mouse-over.
- GMT / UTC doesn't seem to be in the list, the best option seems to be using a city which is always on GMT (eg Rabat, Morocco).
- You can't configure the labels it has to be a city name.
- It doesn't list the country (this is actually genuine issue for me since I have one friend in Santiago, Chile and one in Santiago de Compostela, Spain!)
- I'd prefer something that sits in the system tray rather than on the desktop.

So overall this is about the best bet, but I am really surprised no-one has written anything better!

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than one clock in your taskbar, you could try http://www.1stclock.com/

Comment: that looks like the 90's - and it's paid

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for an app that can show more than 3 time-zones in the taskbar / tooltip.

I found this nice app, which also happens to be free:

[World Time System Stray](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wrldtimesystray/)