# Where are the settings for the Windows 7 clock gadget stored?

Tags: windows-7, clock, desktop-gadget, sidebar

Where are the settings for the Windows 7 clock gadget stored

For information on clock gadgets see here [How to get more than 3 international clocks in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/150063/how-to-get-more-than-3-international-clocks-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the users AppData directory

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\Settings.ini

For example

```
[Section 5]
PrivateSetting_GadgetName="C:%5CProgram%20Files%5CWindows%20Sidebar%5CGadgets%5CClock.Gadget"
PrivateSetting_GadgetDropLocationX="1760"
PrivateSetting_GadgetDropLocationY="49"
PrivateSetting_GadgetSize="small"
SettingsExist="True"
clockName="MyClockName"
themeID="2"
timeZoneIndex="88"
timeZoneBias="-300"
timeZoneDSTBias="-60"
secondsEnabled="False"
timeZoneName="%2528UTC+05%253A00%2529%2520Tashkent"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this can happen, that window with gadgets is empty.

In this case you must copy gadgets from directory `C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets`
(whole directories with gadgets).

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\gadgets
```