# How to reset the Windows 7 desktop gadgets?

Tags: windows-7, sidebar

After changing the Windows Sidebar settings

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\Settings.ini
```

( [Where are the settings for the Windows 7 clock gadget stored?](https://superuser.com/questions/150072/where-are-the-settings-for-the-windows-7-clock-gadget-stored) )

How do i refresh the Windows Sidebar to pick up these changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So far i have discovered killing and restarting "sidebar.exe" works.

But I assume there is a better way?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 7, right click on the desktop, view *Show desktop gadgets*, un-click it, then enable it again.

All the gadgets will initialize.

Comment: Please don't add *special signature* of yours because you've got your own user card which gives your *info* :-)

Comment: In at least my circumstances, that checkbox can't be unchecked, so this answer doesn't work. Simon's suggestion of just whacking `sidebar.exe` and restarting it does work though.

Answer (score 0):

Save the following to a .bat text file and run it (probably as Administrator) :

```
:: Created by: Shawn Brink
:: http://www.sevenforums.com
:: Tutorial:  http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/140358-gadgets-not-displaying-correctly-windows-7-fix.html

taskkill /im sidebar.exe /f
regsvr32 /s msxml3.dll 
regsvr32 /s scrrun.dll
regsvr32 /s jscript.dll
regsvr32 /s atl.dll
Regsvr32 /s "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Sidebar\sbdrop.dll" 
Regsvr32 /s "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Sidebar\wlsrvc.dll"
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones" /f 
"%ProgramFiles%\Windows Sidebar\sidebar.exe"
```

There's a way to make the last command exit the terminal without waiting on the program, but I forget it. You can just close the terminal.