# Need to see many timezone clocks somehow

Tags: windows-7, clock, time-zone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get more than 3 international clocks in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/150063/how-to-get-more-than-3-international-clocks-in-windows-7)

I have Windows 7. It has nice feature to see two timezone clocks on system tray click. But there are two additional clocks only.

I need to constantly view four different timezones. Is there any small application which can help me with that? (Preferably not online but desktop).

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/150063/how-to-get-more-than-3-international-clocks-in-windows-7

Answer (score 2):

use world time clock from www.worldtime-clock.com it shows as many time zones ontop of all the application you are running. So it is always visible on the top.

Comment: Nice app. But I don't need them on top all the time.